# synchronized block in JSP tag class

Tags: java, web-applications, file-io, jsp-tags, concurrentmodification

I am trying to find answer for the following ,for the past couple of days ,but couldnt find comprehensive answer

**Problem Statement**

I have a custom JSP tag class which handles a web form submission ,captures data and write it to same file in the filesystem.
As all web applications,this can be triggeredsimultaneosly ,and i fear that multiple threads would be in action handling each of the submission (we all know thats how Servlet works.)

**CODE**

```
                        synchronized (this){
                        final String reportFileName = "testReport.csv";
                        File reportDir = new File( rootCsDirectory, "reports" );
                        if(!reportDir.isDirectory())reportDir.mkdir();                          
                        File reportFile = new File (reportDir, reportFileName);
                        logReport(reportFile,reportContent.toString());
                        }
```

**ISSUE:**
- A File object can be opened by one thread for writing and at same time another thread might try to access and fail and throw an exception
So i thought of synchronizing (on the object ) should solve the issue , but read some where that **jsp engine would have pool of jsp tag objects**, so i am afraid that 
**synchronized (this)** wont work and it should be changed to
**synchronized (this.getClass())**
**FYI:** The code above is placed in JSP Custom Tag Class.

*EDIT:*

**Question 1:** should the block of code be synchronized by **synchronized (this)** OR  **synchronized (this.getClass())**

**Question 2:** How the same scenario would be handled if the  web application is deployed in the clustered environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would synchronise at a finer level, and choose an object that is more tightly tied to the file creation.

e.g. abstract out the above into a `FileManager` class, and let a *single* instance of that synchronise on a lock object (held internally to the `FileManager` - it could lock on itself, perhaps).

That way you're controlling the synchronisation at a finer level, and you have more control of the objects that you're locking on. They're not controlled by your servlet/web container.

Comment: How the same scenario would be handled if the web application is deployed in the clustered environment ?
Using FileManager will hold good in Clustered environments

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the stuff in the java.util.concurrent package.

You can use a cuncurrent queue to push your updates and have at the other side a thread you spawned when the application started which does the writes to the file system.

This will nicely and efficiently serialize access to that file.

Comment: Actually this package contains many often occuring patterns for dealing with concurrent stuff. Doing synchronisation is hard and have a tendency to come back and bite you. It is far better to not use synchronised directly and use a wrapped library version which has been thoroughly tested and for which the usage semantics are clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting it in a synchronized method so you can cheerfully disregard the detail of how JSPs are managed?